# The number of $2$-simplices and the number of $1$-simplices in a $4$-dimensional simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplex, triangulation, simplicial-complex

Given a $4d$ simplicial complex (a triangulation of $4$-manifold), is there any relation between the number of $2$-simplices (triangles) and the number of $1$-simplices (edges)? Generically, is the number of $2$-simplices always greater than the number of $1$-simplices? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the generic question is a negative. Consider the 4-simplex, it has ten 1-simplices and ten 2-simplices.